# Determining parameters of magnetohydrodynamic plasma equations

Tags: plasma-physics, magnetohydrodynamics

For wide ranges of pressure and temperature, plasma can be described by magnetohydrodynamic (MHD) equations. These equations contains some parameters (resistivity, diffusivity, etc.). I am wondering how these parameters are determined in practice for given values of temperature / pressure within the range of validity of MHD? Can we derive them from the underlying microscopic theory (electrodynamics)? Or do we have to determine these parameters experimentally?

Answer (score 1):

Plasma resistivity has to be measured experimentally, and the measured values are often [much higher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spitzer_resistivity#Disagreements_with_observation) than those predicted by theory. The disagreement is believed to be caused by [acceleration of electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reconnection#Anomalous_resistivity_and_Bohm_diffusion) in the course of magnetic reconnection.